# How does one prove that partial functions of measurable functions of 2 var. are nearly all measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

How does one prove that if $F: X \times Y \to Z$ is measurable for a product measure, then the partial function $F(x,.) : Y \to Z$ (defined by $y \mapsto F(x,y) )$ is measurable for almost all $x$ in $X$? I avoid being more precise for a start so that I have the best chances of getting a usable answer for my purpose. (Some not mentioned hypotheses are probably needed.)

Motivation: In the book *Operator Theory in Function Spaces* by Kehe Zhu integral operators are introduced with $Tf(x) = \int_X K(x,y)f(y)d\mu(y)$ where $K$ and $f$ are in $L^2$ (and therefore measurable) and to make sure that the integral exists it is necessary to have the partial functions also in $L^2$ which will be easy once they are measurable (for almost all $x$)

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "How does one prove that" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath Of course. I had postponed the writing of a good title to after that of the question body - and then forgot about this. I immediately wanted to correct this already before reading your comment

Comment: Please use MathJax throughout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we can prove the following lemma:

> If $E$ is a measurable subset of $X \times Y$, then for any $x \in X$, the slice $E_x := \{ y\in Y: (x,y)\in E\}$ is a measurable subset of $Y$.

To prove this, let $\mathcal E$ be the set of all subsets $E \subset X \times Y$ such that $E_x$ is a measurable subset of $Y$ for all $x \in X$.

Notice that:

- $\mathcal E$ is a sigma algebra: it contains $X \times Y$, and it is closed under taking complements and countable unions.
- $\mathcal E$ contains all measurable rectangles in $X \times Y$.

But the product sigma algebra $\mathcal P$ on $X \times Y$ is by definition the smallest sigma algebra on $X \times Y$ that contains all measurable rectangles. So every set in $\mathcal P$ is also a set in $\mathcal E$, and our lemma is proved.

We now return to your original question:

> Let $F : X \times Y \to Z$ be a measurable function. For some $x \in X$, let $F_x : Y \to Z$ be the slice function, $F_x(y) = F(x, y)$. Then $F_x$ is measurable.

To prove this, consider an open subset $U \subset Z$. We must show that $F_x^{-1}(U)$ is a measurable subset of $Y$.

Since $F$ is measurable, $E := F^{-1}(U)$ is a measurable subset of $X \times Y$. By our lemma, the slice $E_x$ is a measurable subset of $Y$. But $E_x$ is precisely $F_x^{-1}(U)$, so we're done.

---

**Edit:** As per the discussion in the comments below, the OP requires a stronger version of the lemma:

> Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be *complete* measures on $X$ and $Y$. Let $\mu \times \nu$ be the product measure on $X \times Y$, and let $\mathcal P$ be the corresponding sigma algebra. Let $\mathcal P^\star$ be the *completion* of $\mathcal P$ with respect to $\mu \times \nu$. Let $E$ be a subset of $X \times Y$, measurable with respect to $\mathcal P^\star$ (but not necessarily measurable with respect to $\mathcal P$). Then, for *almost all* $x \in X$, the slice $E_x$ is a measurable subset of $Y$.

To prove this, we write $E = A \cup B$, where:

- $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.
- $A$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal P$.
- $B$ is contained inside some set $C$, where $C$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal P$ and has measure zero.

My previous lemma shows that $A_x$ is measurable for all $x$. However, it still remains to show that $B_x$ is measurable, at least for *almost* all $x$. So we have more work to do...

Let's start from the following equation:

$$\int_X \nu(C_x) d\mu(x) = (\mu \times \nu) (C) = 0.$$

[The equation $(\mu \times \nu) (W) = \int_X \nu(W_x) d\mu(x)$ holds for all $\mathcal P$-measurable sets $W$, since this equation is literally the *definition* of the product measure $\mu \times \nu$ on the sigma algebra $\mathcal P$.]

Since $\int_X \nu(C_x) d\mu(x)  = 0$, it must be the case that $\nu(C_x) = 0$, for *almost all* $x \in X$.

Now $B \subset C$, so $B_x \subset C_x$. And by assumption, $Y$ is complete. Thus $B_x$ is measurable and has measure zero, for *almost all* $x \in X$. And we're done.

---

**Another edit:** We still need to prove our final result.

> If $F : X \times Y \to Z$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal P^\star$, then $F_x$ is measurable, for almost all $x \in X$.

As pointed out by the OP in the comments, this is actually quite subtle, and with the results we've established so far, we're going to have to make place some restrictions on $Z$. Let's assume that $Z$ is *second countable*, i.e. the topology for $Z$ has a *countable base* $\mathcal B = \{ U_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$. For example, $Z$ could be $\mathbb C$: in this case, $\mathcal B$ could consist of the open balls with rational centres and rational radii.

For each $n \in \mathbb N$, let $Q_n$ be a null set such that $F_x^{-1}(U_n)$ is measurable for all $x \notin Q_n$. (The existence of such a null set was established by our previous lemma.)

Let $Q = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} Q_n$, which, too, is null, by countable additivity.

Consider an arbitrary open set $U \subset Z$, which can be expressed as $U = \bigcup_{n \in S} U_n$ for some collection of indices $S \subset \mathbb N$.

Observe that $F_x^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{n \in S} F_x^{-1}(U_n)$. If $x \notin Q$, then $F_x^{-1}(U_n)$ is measurable for all $n \in \mathbb N$, and in particular, is measurable for all $n \in S$. Thus $F_x^{-1}(U)$, being the union of at most countably many measurable sets, is measurable, provided that $x \notin Q$.

Thus $F_x$ is a measurable function for all $x \notin Q$, i.e. $F_x$ is measurable for almost all $x$.

Comment: Very good & surprisingly simple. BUT it doesn't totally answer my Q. My first idea was that the lemma is *obviously* wrong, but I couldn't find any error in your proof of it. So what? Eventually I found the source of the problem. Look at this. Take X=Y=the real line and all measures be Lebesgue's. Consider the set M = {a} x B where a is any real nb. & B is a non-measurable set of reals (one knows that with AC such a thing exists). Because M is part of {a} x |R which has measure 0 (in measure theory 0 times infinity = 0), M itself is measurable for L. measure (with measure 0) ... (continued)

Comment: Your $M$ is _not_ measurable with respect to the _product_ sigma algebra formed by taking the product of the two $1$-dimensional Lebesgue sigma algebras. Your $M$ is only measurable with respect to the $2$-dimensional Lebesgue sigma algebra.

Comment: The $2$-dimensional Lebesgue sigma algebra is _not_ the same as the product of two $1$-dimensional Lebesgue sigma algebras. In fact, The $2$-dimensional Lebesgue sigma algebra is the _completion_ of the product of two $1$-dimensional Lebesgue sigma algebras.

Comment: (Last comm't cont.) What this example shows is this: even if the measures on X & Y are complete, the product measure *as you define it* is NOT complete - at least as soon as the singletons on X are measurable with measure 0 & Y contains non-measurable sets ... At least your answer might be an advance to what I need: I need a lemma like yours but with the complete(d) product measure (which obviously should say "for almost all x". Your first step would reduce my Q. to the case of a negligible set of X x Y which seems to me now relatively easy (not trivial)

Comment: Very true! I should be able to answer your extended question too. Give me some time to dig out my notes though...

Comment: @UlysseKeller Please see my edit. Does this answer your question now?

Comment: not completely but I can fill in the still missing parts. First concerning the proof of the extended lemma: AFAIK a measurable set of the completed measure must be taken as $A \Delta B$ where the special sign is a capital delta that means taking the symmetric difference of the two sets,$A$ is measurable on the not completed m. and $B$ is contained in a null set. I know that the union thing suffices in important cases - espec. integrable sets - but this needs not to be the case here. But one has just to adapt your argument accordingly and it seems OK to me - 2nd gap, see next comment

Comment: Now for the result about measurable functions, there is an kind of "uniformity issue" with the extended sit. . Your reciprocal image depends on U (and also the slices of that). Problem is: the exceptional x (where measurability fails) also depend on U .... but when the space Z is a "good" one like the real line or the complex plane (what you probably assume & is sufficient for my needs) one escapes the probl. by realizing that it suffices to consider discs with center 0 (as U) and even only such with rational radius .... then one takes the union of all sets of except's which is still null

Comment: Your second point is very interesting! I should be able to fix this. Give me a moment though...

Comment: There is a problem with A\B which need not be null nor P-measurable. (And the sym. diff. is A\B [disjoint] union B\A.) But I pretend that one can directly argue with the sym. diff. for the lemma: the slicing procedure (at 1 point) is really compatible with nearly every set operation! After your next answer we may stop this - the web app. here is already offering to go to chat, but I think we are practically done

Comment: @UlysseKeller Regarding your second point, I had to look this up in Rudin to find the answer, and it was more subtle than I thought. I've edited again - do take a look. Your observation was very astute, by the way.

Comment: By the way, it's been a real pleasure working on this with you. I've definitely learnt a thing or two!

Comment: Regarding $A\setminus B$, that was wrong on my part. I've edited my comment though and the new version should be correct.

Comment: Oh dear, I realise that my argument _does_ only work when $Z$ is "nice", e.g. $Z = \mathbb R$. That's implicitly assumed in my second edit. Never mind. I'll just make a note of that and call it a day. Thanks for all these insightful comments.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments. I also found it nice with you. Yes, 2nd countable Z is what the final step needs. (At least for a proof on this line.) For my part, I am satisfied and gave you the accept visum for your last version. For others who might look into this, please hold your promise "Regarding A \ B (...) I've edited (...) and the new version should be correct" - I don't see this edit and it should be done in the answer itself. I suggest to just edit your first edit §, replacing the union sign by the delta for sym. diff. and deleting the line saying A,B disjoint (old stuff crossed)

Comment: Oh the point about $E = A \Delta B$ is actually the following. If $C$ is a null set containing $B$,  then let $A' = A \setminus C$ and $B' = (A \Delta B) \cap C$. Then $A'$ and $B'$ are disjoint, and $A'$ is measurable, and $B'$ is contained in $C$, and $E = A' \cap B'$. Thus your definition of the completion agrees with my definition. (My definition, by the way, is taken from Rudin's book.) Sorry, it took me a while to see this. These set manipulations are fiddly and sometimes my brain doesn't work.

Comment: Ha, yet another typo. Should be $E = A' \cup B'$

Comment: OK you showed me that the two def. of the set of measurable sets for the measure completion are equivalent. This was my turn to learn from you. Thanks